# Accessibility of hiking trails in Nepal during December

Tags: hiking, trekking, nepal

I'm planning on Annapurna base camp or Manaslu circuit trek in December (mostly the end of December). I know December is the winter season in Nepal and is expected to be quite cold at that time. Has anyone done either of these trails? The details on the internet aren't that great. Would appreciate if someone who has been on either of these has details regarding the accessibility of these routes in December.

PS: Would love to know if there are other trails which are accessible during December. I'm open to suggestions :)

PPS: Accessibility involves the possible need for equipment to make the hike happen (say ropes and ice axes and all) which in a normal Nepal season would not be required.

Answer (score 5):

I haven't been to Nepal but I currently live in Sichuan, near another edge of the Tibetan plateau. So here's my answer:

Nepal, and everything near it, is in the monsoon climate- rainy in the summer, dry in the winter. Around here, December is a great time to be in the mountains. Clear skies and little chance of bad weather.

Some websites about Manaslu back this up: "[Best views with crystal clear air](http://manaslucircuittrek.com/when-to-trek-the-manaslu-circuit)". Yes it will be cold, but daytime temperatures should be quite comfy, and at night cold & dry is far better than cold & wet. Go for it!

Some websites suggest that things start to shut down in mid December. From my perspective, there is no good reason for that. I'll leave you to do further reading.

Answer (score 1):

Hiking in December in the Himalayan Region of Nepal is quite difficult as compared to another month. The end of December is even more difficult. for [Manaslu Circuit Trek](https://whitehilladventure.com/trip/manaslu-circuit-with-tsum-valley-trek/) you need to pass Larkya La Pass at the height of 5106m from the Sea Level. Whereas ABC is situated at just 4130m high. The temperature in Larkya LA pass may exceed below -16 Celcius, in ABC temperature will be just 5-10 Celcius in the daytime and go up to -5 Celcius in the night   This stat easily shows that ABC Trek is easier than Manaslu Circuit Trek for December.

Comment: You can wrap up for -16C.  The problem comes from too much of the white stuff.